# Instancias Lentas C#

Tags: c#, instanciar-objeto

Estou fazendo a criação de uma instancia de certa classe , e está demorando demais para instanciar .
Alguém tem noção de como faço pra resolver isso ? Do nada as aplicações demoraram para instanciar

código da classe que está demorando à iniciar

```
    public class Email
    {
        public Email()
        {

        }
        string[] auxVerifica;

        string email, destinatario, rastreio, tipoObjeto;

        String nomeDestinatario;

        StringBuilder resultado = new StringBuilder();
        public void metodoParaenviarEmail(){}

    }
```

Eu debugei e ele trava assim que dá o comando new Email();

Comment: Yuri, sem trecho de código fica difícil ajudar, pode ser vários motivos, até uma conexão com o banco de dados, teria que investigar o que o construtor da classe está fazendo.

Comment: Não. Não há como ajudar sem informações relevantes. Mostre o código, explique melhor o esperado, o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Aí que está , ele não chega nem a iniciar o construtor , ele demora a partir do momento que dou o comenado Email n =  new Email();

Comment: Achei que fosse o construtor , mas o construtor está vazio , está travando na hora de criar a instancia mesmo

Comment: Se possível adiciona o código da classe Email a tua pergunta

Comment: Pronto Adicionei o código da classe